# How do you make SeleniumRC open Firefox windows without focusing them?

Tags: selenium

Whenever I run a SeleniumRC script (using Ruby's selenium-client), the
Firefox instance opens in front of all my other windows. This is a bit
annoying. Is there a way to make it run behind my focused window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Linux you can use [XVFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) and then tell Selenium to use the new virtual display.

More details can be found [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SRC/Selenium-RC+and+Continuous+Integration) but essentially its

1. startx -- `which Xvfb` :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 2>&1 >/dev/null &
2. DISPLAY=:1 java -jar selenium-server.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you can use the [desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) tool which provides you with multiple desktops which you can switch between. With that tool installed you can start RC on a different desktop and firefox won't be launched on your primary desktop anymore.